# Simple Donate error

Tags: civicontribute, simple-donate-form

I'm trying to use the Simple Donate extension on my website, and I keep getting an error that says "One of parameters (value: ) is not of the type Integer"

I've tried deleting, uninstalling & clearing cache several times, and still get the error.

PS
I'm running Civi 5.20.2 on Wordpress

PPS
I was FINALLY able to resolve this by removing the Price Set. I'm now running into an error of not being able to view the Live Page (Test works fine).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!  If you're looking for an answer on the live page issue, I recommend starting a new question.  You can also post an answer rather than edit the question; this helps other folks vote it up, which makes it clearer to others with the same problem that there's a solution.  If you'd like guidance on the original error, consider enabling debug and backtrace (in **Administer menu » System Settings » Debugging and Error Handling**) and replicating the problem.  You'll get a much more detailed error, which you can edit your question to include.

Answer (score 1):

(Copying the resolution from the question into an answer)

From the question author:
"I was FINALLY able to resolve this by removing the Price Set."

Comment: I solved the FIRST problem... I'm now running into an error of not being able to view the Live Page (Test works fine).